# How does lock works when delete rows through secondary index in InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, database-design, index, innodb

## step1: InnoDB Transaction Isolation Level

Repeated Read.

## step2: Table schema

```
CREATE TABLE `follows` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `followable_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `followable_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `type_first` (`followable_type`,`followable_id`),
  KEY `id_first` (`followable_id`,`followable_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

## step3: prepare test data

```
insert into follows(followable_type, followable_id) values ("Post", 6);
insert into follows(followable_type, followable_id) values ("Post", 22);
insert into follows(followable_type, followable_id) values ("Post", 28);
insert into follows(followable_type, followable_id) values ("Post", 32);
insert into follows(followable_type, followable_id) values ("Post", 34);
```

## step4: begin two transactions

### Session1

```
session1> begin;
session1> delete from follows where followable_id=28;
```

### Session2

```
session2> begin;
session2> insert into follows(followable_type, followable_id) value ("Post", 22);  
Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

session2>insert into follows(followable_type, followable_id) value ("Post", 28);  
Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

session2>insert into follows(followable_type, followable_id) value ("Post", 32);  
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

## Test Result

MySQL manual claim

> `DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...` sets an exclusive next-key lock on every record the search encounters.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html

Actually, session1 locked this range [22, 32), which consists of

- record locks (those index records equal 22)
- a next key lock(22, 28]
- a gap lock (28, 32)

> Meaning of() (]
>
> - (): Gap lock is a lock on a gap between index records, I use bracket () to stand for.
> - (] Next key lock is a combination of a record lock on the index record and a gap lock on the gap before the index record. I use (] stand for it.

If manual is right, the result should be (22, 28]. So I really confused by conflict between test result and MySQL manual:

1. How to explain the conflict?
2. Could you explain the meaning of `DELETE FROM ... WHERE ... sets an exclusive next-key lock on every record the search encounters.`

Answer (score 1):

(Semi-related comments...)

Assuming this is a standard many-to-many mapping table, get rid of `id` entirely.  Then make one of the other `KEYs` (either one) the `PRIMARY KEY`.  More tips [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

If the `DELETE` is typical, then I would make the `KEY` starting with `followable_id` the `PRIMARY KEY`.

This will speed up the inserts and the deletes, thereby tending to avoid deadlocks and "lock waits".

Comment: What other answer?